# Ошибка при компиляции примера из книги Хорстманна и Корнеги "Java.Библиотека профессионала"

Tags: java, cmd

Столкнулся с проблемой компиляции примеров из 5-ой главы данной книги. В предыдущих главах проблем не возникала. Пример компилирую из конкретного пакета в котором он находится. В пакете есть нужные классы, но все равно компилятор ругается. Вариант с компиляцией из иср не предлагайте, т.к хочу научиться работать с командной строкой.

Код :

```
package arrayList;

import java.util.*;



/**
* This program demonstrates the ArrayList class.
* @version 1.11 2012-01-26
* @author Cay Horstmann
*/


public class ArrayListTest{

public static void main(String[] args){


  // fill the staff array list with three Employee objects


  ArrayList<Employee> staff = new ArrayList<>();


  staff.add(new Employee("Carl Cracker", 75000, 1987, 12, 15));

  staff.add(new Employee("Harry Hacker", 50000, 1989, 10, 1));

  staff.add(new Employee("Tony Tester", 40000, 1990, 3, 15));



  // raise everyone's salary by 5%


  for (Employee e : staff)

     e.raiseSalary(5);



  // print out information about all Employee objects


  for (Employee e : staff)


     System.out.println("name=" + e.getName() + ",salary=" + e.getSalary() + ",hireDay="

           + e.getHireDay());

  }

 }
```

Еще

```
package arrayList;


import java.util.Date;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class Employee{

  private String name;

  private double salary;

  private Date hireDay;



  public Employee(String n, double s, int year, int month, int day){

  name = n;
  salary = s;
  GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1,day);
  hireDay = calendar.getTime();

}



public String getName(){

    return name;

}



public double getSalary(){

    return salary;

}



public Date getHireDay(){

    return hireDay;

}



public void raiseSalary(double byPercent){


    double raise = salary * byPercent / 100;

    salary += raise;

 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, вы сами себе враг. Учитесь языку отдельно, работе с командной строкой отдельно.

Comment: И если вы и правда хотите, чтобы вам помогли, выложите, пожалуйста, **код**, который не компилируется. В виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: По картинке видно только, что компилятор не видит класс Employee. Вы его в classpath добавили? Раз уж вы собрались компилировать из командной строки, внимательно изучите параметры javac.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы компилируете в каталоге `arrayList`, компилятор считает, что это корень вашей иерархии классов. И если вы ссылаетесь на класс `arrayList.Employee`, он пытается найти соответствующий файл внутри каталога, то есть `arrayList/arrayList/Employee.java`. Конечно, такого файла нет, и поэтому вы видите ошибку. Лучше компилировать, находясь в корне иерархии классов:

```
...\CoreJavaBook\v1ch05> javac arrayList\ArrayListTest.java
```

Альтернатива — указать путь к классам явно:

```
...\CoreJavaBook\v1ch05\arrayList> javac -cp .. ArrayListTest.java
```

Запускать класс тоже надо находясь в корне иерархии классов:

```
...\CoreJavaBook\v1ch05> java arrayList.ArrayListTest
```

Или указывая явно путь к корню:

```
...\CoreJavaBook\v1ch05\arrayList> java -cp .. arrayList.ArrayListTest
```

В заключение скажу, что писать свои файлы внутрь `C:\Program Files` плохо. Для этого есть домашний каталог (например, `C:\Users\7even` или что-то похожее).

Comment: Угу, ТС пишет в Program Files, и для этого запустил шелл от администратора :-\

Comment: @Tagir Valeev Спасибо большое!